# Integral over triple product of spherical Bessel functions

Tags: analysis, integration

I would like to carry out symbolically the following integral

$$\int_0^\infty d r \,r^2\, j_0( k r)\, j_0( k_1 r)\,  j_0( k_2 r)\,, $$
where $j_0(r)$ is the zeroth order spherical Bessel function and $k$,$k_1$ and $k_2$ are real numbers.

**Idea?**

I am wondering if I should use this expansion

$$J_\alpha (\beta) = \sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^m}{m!\Gamma(m+\alpha +1)} \left(\frac{\beta}{2}\right)^{2m}$$

from [this reference](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/141589/calculation-of-bessel-functions)

**Clue**

If I am to believe *Mathematica* 
$$\int_0^\infty d r \,r^2\, j_0(  r)\, j_0( 2 r)\,  j_0( 3 r)=\frac{\pi}{48}$$
for instance, so the integral seems possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$
\begin{align}
&\int_0^\infty\mathrm drr^2j_0(k_1r)j_0(k_2r)j_0(k_3r)
\\
=&
\int_0^\infty\mathrm dr\frac{\sin k_1r\sin k_2r\sin k_3r}{k_1k_2k_3r}
\\
=&
\int_0^\infty\mathrm dr\frac{\sin(k_1+k_2-k_3)r+\sin(k_2+k_3-k_1)r+\sin(k_3+k_1-k_2)r-\sin(k_1+k_2+k_3)r}{4k_1k_2k_3r}
\\
=&
\frac{\pi\left(\def\sgn{\operatorname{sgn}}\sgn(k_1+k_2-k_3)+\sgn(k_2+k_3-k_1)+\sgn(k_3+k_1-k_2)-\sgn(k_1+k_2+k_3)\right)}{8k_1k_2k_3}\;.
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Thanks a lot! It always looks so simple in retrospect; I feel a bit embarrassed.

Comment: @chris: You're welcome!