# Definite integral over triple products of higher order Bessel functions.

Tags: analysis, integration

As a follow up to this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/245563/integral-over-triple-product-of-spherical-bessel-functions) I am also interested in a symbolic closed form for this integral

$$\int_0^\infty d r \,r^2\, j_{n_1}( k_1 r)\, j_{n_2}( k_2 r)\,  j_{n_3}( k_3 r)\,, $$
where $j_n(r)$ is the $n^{\rm th}$ order spherical Bessel function, $k_1$,$k_2$ and $k_3$ are real positive numbers and $n_1,n_2$ and $n_3$ are positive integers.

The spherical Bessel function $j_n$ can be defined by 
$$ j_n(x) = (-x)^n \left(\frac{1}{x}\frac{d}{dx}\right)^n\,\frac{\sin x}{x}.$$

**Clue**

As an answer to this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/245563/integral-over-triple-product-of-spherical-bessel-functions), @joriki provided a nice solution for $n_1=n_2=n_3=0$.

If I am to believe *Mathematica* again, for instance
$$\int_0^\infty d r \,r^2\, j_2(  r)\, j_2( 2 r)\,  j_2( 3 r)=-\frac{\pi}{48}$$
and
$$\int_0^\infty d r \,r^2\, j_2(  r)\, j_4( 2 r)\,  j_4( 3 r)=-\frac{\pi}{48}$$
 so the integral seems possible. On the other hand, if some $n_i$ are odd the integral seems ill defined.

I would guess that for odd indices the answer is $\pi/(8k_1 k_2 k_3)$ times some function of the signs of $n_1$, $n_2$ and $n_3$.

**Update**

My guess seems to be wrong. Symbolic integration for the first $8\times8\times 8 $ values of $(n_1,n_2,n_3)$ yields (with $k_1=k_2=k_3=1$)

[image: graphics]

Comment: You should try to use integration by parts on the Bessel function given by the mentioned formula.

Comment: @Phira thanks for the advice; it seems difficult to do in practice since 3 such functions are involved??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

R. Mehrem gives this as equation 5.14 in the paper  [The Plane Wave Expansion, Infinite Integrals and Identities involving Spherical Bessel Functions](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0909.0494v4.pdf) (arXiv:0909.0494v4). It looks like this:

[image: Mehrem paper screenshot]

The symbols in curly braces are Wigner 6j-symbols, and the angle-bracketed letters are Clebsch-Gordan coefficients.  The P_l is a Legendre polynomial, and Delta is k1^2+k2^2-k3^2/(2k1k2), coming from applying law of cosines to a triangle in k-space (it is just cos theta_12)).  The beta function is zero unless the k1, k2, k3 combination is such that it forms a closed triangle (i.e. the side lengths satisfy the triangle inequality).

Comment: Please summarize the relevant information from the paper.

Comment: Thank you  for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

There is also a more recent paper that appears to have a simpler approach: http://www.ams.org/journals/qam/2013-71-03/S0033-569X-2012-01300-8/

I'm not sure if you can access it without institutional credentials, though (I got it through my institution).  If you can, the relevant equations are (5) and (9), with q=2.